# how to add Webview in tableview cell and get dynamic height of cell with webview in ios

Tags: ios, webview

hi all I want to add webview in tableview cell , please suggest how to add webview in tablview cell and get dynamic height of tableview cell with web view in ios

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

It's very important question and After lots of r&d I have implemented that in my code with html code and native string with WKWebview inside UITableviewcell with dynamic height in MVVM architecture.

Please check below code which i have implemented in my code and it's working fine.

1. I have used xib for cell and Storyboard for tableview.
2. First I have taken tableview inside storyboard and implemented in my viewcontroller and linked it.
3. Created tablview cell xib and designed it based on my requirement.
4. I have taken UItextview for simple text show and WKWebview for show html content.
   [image]

5. Here is my viewcontroller code.

import UIKit

```
class FeedListVC: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet weak var feedListTblView: UITableView!

private var viewModel = FeedViewModel.shared

// MARK: - Life Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configreTableView()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.feedHeightUpdateNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(NotificationName.UPDATE_FEED_WEBVIEW_HEIGHT), object: nil)
        
}

func configreTableView() {
        
        self.viewModel.feedListArr?.removeAll()
        
        feedListTblView.delegate = self
        feedListTblView.dataSource = self
        feedListTblView.backgroundColor = .white
        feedListTblView.separatorStyle = .none
        feedListTblView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        feedListTblView.estimatedRowHeight = 210
        feedListTblView.register(UINib(nibName: NibName.feedListXib, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: FeedListTblCell.identifier)
        
        
    }

// MARK: - Notification Method
    
    @objc func feedHeightUpdateNotification(notification: Notification) {
        let notificationData = notification.object as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
        
        let height = notificationData["height"] as? CGFloat ?? 0.0
        let index = notificationData["index"] as? Int ?? 0
        if let feedArry = self.viewModel.feedListArr, feedArry.count > 0 {
            if self.viewModel.feedListArr?[index].webViewHeight ?? 0.0 < 1 {
                self.viewModel.feedListArr?[index].webViewHeight = height
                reloadFeedTableView()
            }
        }
    }

func reloadFeedTableView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                let loc = self.feedListTblView.contentOffset
                self.feedListTblView.reloadData()
                self.feedListTblView.contentOffset = loc
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - TableView Delegate & DataSource
extension FeedListVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.feedListArr?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FeedListTblCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? FeedListTblCell else { fatalError("xib does not exists") }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        if let item = self.viewModel.feedListArr?[indexPath.row] {

            cell.index = indexPath.row
            cell.configureCell(feedItem: item)
        }
        return cell
    }
        
}
```

6. My Tableview Cell looks like below.

   ```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class FeedListTblCell: UITableViewCell {

        // MARK: - Properties

        @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var topSeparatorLine: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
        @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

        @IBOutlet weak var webViewHeightConsraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

        class var identifier: String { return String(describing: self) }

        var index:Int?

        // MARK: - Life Cycle

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            initView()
        }

        func initView() {
            // Cell view customization
            backgroundColor = .clear
            self.bgView.backgroundColor = .white

        }

        override func prepareForReuse() {
            super.prepareForReuse()
           // print("reuse called")
            self.bgView.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.textView.text = nil

        }

        func configureCell(feedItem: FeedItem) {

            /// Post Text
            if let postText = feedItem.postText {
               // print("post text ==> \(postText)")

                var htmlString =  "<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><style type='text/css'> @font-face { font-family: 'Inter-Regular'; src: url('Inter-Regular.ttf'); } p {font-size: 14px !important; font-family: 'Inter-Regular' !important;} b {font-size: 14px !important; font-family: 'Inter-Bold' !important;} span {font-size: 14px !important; font-family: 'Inter-Regular' !important;} strong {font-size: 14px !important; font-family: 'Inter-Regular' !important;} a {font-size: 14px !important; font-family: 'Inter-Regular' !important;} *{background: none}</style></head><body>"
                htmlString = htmlString + "\(postText)" +  ("</body></html> ")

                if htmlString.contains("</math>") {
                    self.webViewHeightConsraint.constant = feedItem.webViewHeight ?? 0.0
                    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
                    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
                    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = false
                    self.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
                    self.webView.backgroundColor = .clear
                    self.webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear

                    self.webView.isHidden = false
                    self.textView.isHidden = true
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
                    }
                }else{
                    self.webViewHeightConsraint.constant = 0.0
                    self.webView.isHidden = true
                    self.textView.isHidden = false

                    self.textView.attributedText = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString
                    self.richTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
                }

            }

        }

    }
   ```

   extension FeedListTblCell :WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

   ```
    internal func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.webViewHeightConsraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(NotificationName.UPDATE_FEED_WEBVIEW_HEIGHT), object: ["height":webView.scrollView.contentSize.height,"index":self.index!])
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard case .linkActivated = navigationAction.navigationType,
              let url = navigationAction.request.url
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { (success) in
                })
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }
7. FeedItem is my model which have webViewHeight key and by-default value is 0.

It's looks like below :

```
// MARK: - Item
struct FeedItem: Codable {
    let postText: String?
    var webViewHeight: CGFloat?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case postText = "post_text"
        case webViewHeight = "webViewHeight"
    }
}
```

I have used webview for display Math type equations so when first time my tableview load that time inside cell i am checking that it's have math equation then show in webview else display html code in Textview.

First time in webview i am passing height 0 and after load webview i am updating my webview's hight and by using of post notification method i am notifying on my viewcontroller and  updating that height on my model item which have in my array with index.

On my viewcontroller i am checking that if webViewHeight is 0 then only update and reload tableview otherwise no need to update because we have already webview's height.

It's working fine and Not creating problem for performance inside tableview.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductsViewCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = 
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) 
    cell =
        [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIWebView* webView = [[UISynchedWebView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    webView.tag = 1001;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webView.opaque = NO;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell addSubview:webView];
  }

  UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
  if (isHTML) {
     UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0f];
     NSString *html =
     [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<html>\n"
     "<head>\n"
     "</head>\n"
     "<body><div style=\"padding:5px 0px; text-align:center\"><b>test</b></div></body>\n"
     "</html>"];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html
                    baseURL:nil];
    webView.hidden = NO;
 } else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Not HTML";
    webView.hidden = YES;
 }

  return cell;
}
```

If you dynamically change height use the below `webView` methods,

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView {

    CGRect frame = awebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    awebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [awebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    awebView.frame = frame;

    self.cellSize = fittingSize.height;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    NSLog(@"Calling webViewDidFinishLoad. Cell size value: %lf",   self.cellSize);

}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: not exactly , but i find the solution  from this and add textview with user interaction and get required response

Answer (score 0):

Code for get the height of the cell but not for webview its calculate the height of the cell:

CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(300.0f , CGFLOAT_MAX);

CGRect textRect = [strmessage boundingRectWithSize:constraint1  options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0]} context:nil];

```
CGFloat msgHight = MAX(textRect.size.height,40.0f);
return msgHight
```