# Add a Webview in a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I put a WebView in a tableViewCell and I use it in a tableView. Until now everything is working fine. But I was using a fixed size for the WebViewCell. Now I want to show all the content of the WebView. I changed my code to this one in the `MyTbaleView` class

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

     if let cell = modelCollection[collection.identifier] {
            if let _ = cell as? TiteCell{
              return 200
             } else if let _ = cell as? myWebViewCell{
              return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
             }
     }



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, EstimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 1000
}
```

and this is the xib file

[myWebView Xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKjLx.png)

With this code the WebView become really small, a few millimeters. I tried to add this code I found in the forum to `MyWebViewCell` class

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        var frame = myWebView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1
        myWebView.frame = frame

        let fittingSize = myWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
        frame.size = fittingSize
        myWebView.frame = frame
        myWebView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now the webview is a little bit bigger, 1 centimeter and the width is larger than the ipad width.

Comment: Webview in a tableviewcell? That is a costly process, you have to think about re-designing. If you just want rich text, you can use NSAttributedString in a UILabel.

Comment: I just want to load a web page from the internet and show it in a table view cell

Comment: Did you tried by setting Scale pages to fit property?

Comment: I just tired to add myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true but didn't helped

Comment: I have implemented dynamic height webview inside tableview with performance handling. Please check below link for full sample code for dynamic height of webview inside tableview cell. Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73248593/4941151

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramaraj T said, its a very costlier process and I to approve that you should change your design. But if you still want to continue you can do something like this.

Create a HeightConstraint for WebView in your custom cell.

```
// Code in cell
var webViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstarint!

// Code in controller 
// code cellForIndexPath
webView.tag = indexPath.row(or any unique value which can be used to calculate indexPath)

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
   var frame = myWebView.frame
   frame.size.height = 1
   myWebView.frame = frame

   let fittingSize = myWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
   frame.size = fittingSize
   myWebView.frame = frame
   myWebView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

   let height = myWebView.contentSize.height
   let section = webView.tag
   let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section)
   let cell = tableView.dequeCell(atIndexPath: indexPath)// 
   cell.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
   cell.layoutConstraintsIfNeeded()
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.endUpdates()
}
```